# Add multiple products to cart using Magento2 REST API using custom method

Tags: magento2, product, api, addtocart, rest-api

Add multiple products to cart using Magento2 REST API using custom method
Their is no default magento api 
this is single product add to cart json code in rest api body section.

```
{ "cartItem": 
   { 
     "quote_id": "ee6e72fc6e3226558197d23cb1f88cbe", 
     "sku": "24-MB02",
     "qty": 1
   }
}
```

i am trying to modify the above code to bellow format and did respected changes in webapi.xml, inteface and model

```
{ "cartItem": 
  [
   { 
     "quote_id": "ee6e72fc6e3226558197d23cb1f88cbe", 
     "sku": "24-MB02",
     "qty": 1
   },
  { 
    "quote_id": "ee6e72fc6e3226558197d23cb1f88cbe", 
    "sku": "24-MB03",
    "qty": 2 
   }
 ]
}
```

vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/guest-cart/:cartId/item" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface" method="saveData"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface.php

```
    public function saveData(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem);
```

vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartItemRepository.php

in model i am stuck

```
public function saveData(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem)
{
    /** @var $quoteIdMask QuoteIdMask */
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartItem->getQuoteId(), 'masked_id');
    $cartItem->setQuoteId($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
    return $this->repository->save($cartItem);
}
```

is it possible
Can any one please hlep me,
Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score -1):

**For Guest:**

**POST:** Create a Guest Cart

http://test.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/

**POST:** Add multiple products to the cart

http://test.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/94b93061280ddc2e050e196203ba598b/

In Postman, Body=>Raw=>json add bellow code

{ "products": [

{ "quote_id": "94b93061280ddc2e050e196203ba598b","pid": "2354", "qty":1 },

{ "quote_id": "94b93061280ddc2e050e196203ba598b","pid": "2353", "qty":1 },

{ "quote_id": "94b93061280ddc2e050e196203ba598b","pid": "2352", "qty":1 }

]

}

**GET:** Cart items

http://test.com/rest/V1/guest-multicart/

**For Registered Customer:**

**POST:** Customer login

http://test.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=nagendra.k@test.com&password=rest@123

**POST:** Add multiple products to the cart

http://test.com/rest/V1/carts/mine

In Postman, Body=>Raw=>json add bellow code

{ "products": [

{ "quote_id": "6","pid": "2354", "qty":1 },

{ "quote_id": "6","pid": "2353", "qty":1 },

{ "quote_id": "6","pid": "2352", "qty":1 }

]

}

**GET:** Cart items

http://test.com/rest/V1/cart/mine-multicart

Sky\Mobileshop\etc\webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/guest-multicart" method="POST">
<service class="Sky\Mobileshop\Api\GuestmulticartInterface"                                                   method="guestmulticart"/>
<resources>
    <resource ref="anonymous"/>
</resources>
```

Sky\Mobileshop\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Sky\Mobileshop\Api\GuestmulticartInterface" type="Sky\Mobileshop\Model\Guestmulticart" />
<preference for="Sky\Mobileshop\Api\MinemulticartInte" type="Sky\Mobileshop\Model\Minemulticart" />
```

Sky\Mobileshop\Api\GuestmulticartInterface.php

```
    <?php
namespace Sky\Mobileshop\Api;
interface GuestmulticartInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function guestmulticart($products);
}
?>
```

Sky\Mobileshop\Model\Guestmulticart.php

```
<?php
namespace Sky\Mobileshop\Model;

use Sky\Mobileshop\Api\GuestmulticartInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;

class Guestmulticart implements GuestmulticartInterface

{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     * @var QuoteIdMaskFactory
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */

    protected $obj;

    protected $request;

    protected $cart;

    protected $product;

    protected $customerSession;

    protected $quoteFactory;

    protected $quoteRepository;

    protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $obj
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cart
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param \CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
     */

    public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\State $obj,

    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,

    \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cart,

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,

    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,

    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,

    CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,

    QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
)
    {

        $this->obj = $obj;

        $this->request = $request;

        $this->cart = $cart;

        $this->_product = $product;

        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;

        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;

        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;

    }

    public function guestmulticart($products)

    {

        try
        {

            $pid = array();
            $pids = array();
            $itemids = array();

            $cart = $this
                ->cart
                ->getCart();

            foreach ($products as $name => $value)
            {

                $pid = $value['pid'];

                $qty = $value['qty'];

                $quote_id = $value['quote_id'];

                $quoteIdMask = $this
                    ->quoteIdMaskFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->load($quote_id, 'masked_id');

                $quote = $this
                    ->quoteFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->load($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());

                array_push($pids, $pid, $qty);

                $product = $this
                    ->_product
                    ->load($pid);

                $quoteItems = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

                $quote->save();

                $quote->collectTotals()
                    ->save();

            }

            return "Guest Quote Id: " . $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {

            return $e;

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Sky\Mobileshop\Api\MinemulticartInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Sky\Mobileshop\Api;

interface MinemulticartInterface

{

    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function minemulticart($products);

}

?>
```

Sky\Mobileshop\Model\Minemulticart.php

```
<?php
namespace Sky\Mobileshop\Model;

use Sky\Mobileshop\Api\MinemulticartInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;

class Minemulticart implements MinemulticartInterface

{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     * @var QuoteIdMaskFactory
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */

    protected $obj;

    protected $request;

    protected $cart;

    protected $product;

    protected $customerSession;

    protected $quoteFactory;

    protected $quoteRepository;

    protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $obj
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cart
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param \CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
     */

    public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\State $obj,

    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,

    \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cart,

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,

    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,

    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,

    CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,

    QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
)
    {

        $this->obj = $obj;

        $this->request = $request;

        $this->cart = $cart;

        $this->_product = $product;

        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;

        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;

        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;

    }

    public function minemulticart($products)

    {

        try
        {

            $cart = $this
                ->cart
                ->getCart();

            foreach ($products as $name => $value)
            {

                $pid = $value['pid'];

                $qty = $value['qty'];

                $quote_id = $value['quote_id'];

                $quote = $this
                    ->quoteFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->load($quote_id);

                $product = $this
                    ->_product
                    ->load($pid);

                $quoteItems = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

                $quote->save();

                $quote->collectTotals()
                    ->save();

            }

            return "Customer Quote Id: " . $quote_id;

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {

            return $e;

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: blog not found.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.